# Angular 4 switch navigation design in each view

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-routing

I have one shared navigation and content is changed by routerModule. Is there any solution how can i change design of navigation in each view?

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**for example**


**in view:** /blue 
I want blue nav

**in view:** /red
I want red nav

Or i must create one nav in each view?

Thank for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `app-navigation` component can listen to navigation events, and change its appearance based on the path or the route data.

Inject `Router` into your component, and subscribe to it's `events` property:

```ts
constructor(router: Router) { router.events.subscribe(...); }
```

There you can inspect the URL or the route snapshot and change appearance accordingly.